# how to send page control to function from another page in asp

Tags: asp.net

i have this function.

```
public bool CheckAccess(Page Page, Control Control)
{
}
```

i'm in the "GoodLink.aspx" and i want to send this page "Default.aspx" to CheckAccess function

How to i can do this work.
pleas help me.

Answer (score 0):

Create a base class:

```
public class BasePage : Page
{
    public bool CheckAccess(..) { }
}
```

Have all your pages inherit from this.  Each page can call this when it needs to.  But GoodLink.aspx cannot call this for Default.aspx; you'd have to redirect to Default.aspx, that page does the check, and redirect away if false.

Comment: I need this page because i'm in "goodlink.aspx" and i want to send script in "Defaul.aspx" but i can't send "Default.aspx" page to from "Goddlink.aspx" to CheckAccess Function

Comment: Pages can never communicate with each other.  When you say "send", what to you mean?  "Redirect", send data to a page, open as a popup, what?

Comment: i need to "Default.aspx" until add a Script to page from "GoodLink.aspx" and i can't send page to function CheckAccess